# Can't Connect Kotlin and MongoDB project with Docker

Tags: mongodb, docker, gradle, docker-compose

I can't connect my kotlin/gradle project up with mongodb. I keep seeing an error

```
INFO org.mongodb.driver.cluster  - Exception in monitor thread while connecting to 
server mongo:27017
#10 90.53 com.mongodb.MongoSocketException: mongo: Name does not resolve
```

mongo.localhost.properties

```
hostName=mongo
port=27017
```

Dockerfile

```
FROM gradle:4.3.1-jdk8-alpine
WORKDIR /app
ADD --chown=gradle:gradle . /app
USER root
RUN apk update
RUN apk add git
RUN ./gradlew runLocalhost --info
```

docker-compose.yml

```
version: "3.7"
services:
 backend:
   build: .
   restart: always
   ports:
    - 3000:3000
  links:
    - mongo
  depends_on:
    - mongo
 mongo:
  image: "mongo:4.4.3"
  container_name: "mongo"
  hostname: mongo
  restart: always
  ports:
    - 27017:27017
  command: ["--bind_ip", "0.0.0.0"]
```